# Cast bit(64) to boolean in Postgres

Tags: postgresql, types, casting, bitwise-operators

I know you can cast an int8 to a boolean like so:

```
int8::int4::boolean
```

Now I'm trying to cast an `int8` to a `bit(64)`, `AND` that with a `bit(64)` mask, and then evaluate the entire expression as a boolean (ie. `true` iff at least one bit is `1`).

But `bit(64)::int4::boolean` doesn't work.

What does?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see no need for that, since there are bit-wise ooerators:

```
WHERE intcol & 127 <> 0
```

Comment: Well my ignorance was one reason. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out quickly; might as well share.

In order to cast a `bit(64)` to a boolean, you can do:

```
bit(64)::int8::int4::boolean
```

There must be a better way...

What would be the harm in evaluating a 64-bit expression as a true/false predicate, like in so many programming languages?

Comment: You can create a custom CAST() to do it for you. https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createcast.html